# TFS Builds: Running the builds as administrator

Tags: tfs, msbuild

We have one of our build projects that modifies the registry on the build machine (don't ask me why) and it needs to be done as administrator.
Is there some way to run msdev from the build agent as "administrator"?
We're using TFS 2012, soon to move to TFS 2013.
- Bruce

Answer (score 3):

Add the build service account to the local Administrators group

Comment: How exactly do we do that? While it is an answer, it could be more specific and therefore useful

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's late - adding to Vian's answer, adding the account to the local Admin groups is probably the way to go here. Someone who is an Admin on the computer will have to do this.

1. In the start menu type in "User". It will come up as "Edit Local Users and Groups". Click on that.
2. In the window that just opened, Under Groups -> Administrators (double click to edit properties of Admin Group). Add the Build Machine Account.