# Deploying web packages with MSDEPLOY

Tags: package, azure-devops, iis-8, msdeploy

I've built my packages and read through this docs @ http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/deploying-web-packages

And it seems to suggest that the problem should be relatively simple from here as the instructions clearly show ...

```
[project name].deploy.cmd [/T | /Y]
                          [/M:<computer name>]
                          [/A:<Basic | NTLM>]
                          [/U:<user name>]
                          [/P:<password>]
                          [/L]
                          [/G:<true | false>]
                          [Additional MSDeploy.exe flags]
```

.. so, no problem I thought I will give the command params like this ...

```
myproj.deploy.cmd /Y /M:test.foo.com /A:basic /U:<my user> /P:<my pass>
```

... where the user and pass are an admin account on my server.

For some reason though this results in a 401 ...

```
Error code: EEROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN
More Information: Connected to 'server' using the Web Deployment Agent Service but could not authorize. Make sure you are an administrator on 'server'
```

... well, I used my admin credentials, the same ones I used with VS for the one click deploy and they worked in VS so how come they aren't working on the command line when pushing the package?

...

EDIT:

I looked through the logs, checked out the ms deploy command it was generating and decided to skip the cmd file altogether and go straight to ms deploy myself.

I found the command it was generating and cleaned it up to something like this ...

```
msdeploy.exe
  -source:package='..\package.zip' 
  -dest:auto,computerName=test.foo.com,userName=<me>,password=<my pass>,authtype=basic,includeAcls=False 
  -verb:sync 
  -disableLink:AppPoolExtension 
  -disableLink:ContentExtension 
  -disableLink:CertificateExtension
```

Apparently my account when used in this context is not an admin (a total lie or perhaps I missed something).

here's what technet has to say on it: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd569106(v=ws.10).aspx

which links to this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd569001(v=ws.10).aspx

which states ...

> The Web Deployment Tool does not perform local impersonation. If you
>   provide values for the username and password provider settings but do
>   not specify the name of a remote computer for the computerName
>   setting, the credentials that you provide will have no effect.

does this mean because I am specifying a domain name and not a machine name the credentials I am specifying have been ignored?

If so ... how am I supposed to do this?

Comment: Does your account have IIS root level admin permission? Or just site level?

Comment: my account is in the admins group for the machine (making me a system wide admin)

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT with changing no permissions I can do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953775/ms-deploy-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apprently undocumented anyway ... the answer is ...

You can't run MS deploy commands that talk to the MSDeploy service on the same machine.

No idea why, this makes no sense, but taking the same command and executing it on another box seems to work fine even when deploying to the same box I had the issue on.

Well done Microsoft ... way to make a Team Services Admins life a dream!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a domain account you should set the authType to "NTLM".

Comment: The windows domain is different to the web domain being used here, the windows domain is a domain owned by the host of our servers which we have no accounts for so I can only use machine accounts ... that must work as I can do this through VS ... trouble I don't know how to get the command that VS runs when I use one click publish.

Comment: Have you tried enabling verbose MSBuild logging in VS? https://rauofthameem.wordpress.com/2012/07/21/visual-studio-detailed-output-of-msbuild-in-output-window/

Comment: the problem isn't an MSBuild issue it's MSDeploy which although is part of my build process is a completely separate thing.